# Connect to mongodb database dynamically using mongoengine

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, mongoengine

I try to connect `mongodb` database using `mongoengine` with dynamic connection. i getting database name from URL Request. the problem is its connected only first url database.

here is mycode

**run.py**

```
from application import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8089)
```

**routes.py**

```
from flask import request
from application import app
from mongoengine import connect

class DBConnection():
    def __init__(self):
        database = request.url.split("/")[2].split(".")[0]
        print(database)
        connect(database,alias='default')

@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def index():
    try:
        DBConnection();
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

in above code when i hit url **mydomain.maindomain.com** it will be connected **mydomain** and hit url **yourdomain.maindomain.com** it will be connect with **yourdomain**

the problem is it connect with only one database. for example first time i hit     **mydomain.maindomain.com** then database is every time connect with **mydomain** even if i hit **yourdomain.maindomain.com** its show **mydomain** database record.

Comment: Why you store `routes` ? Every request required new `db_connection` but you stored by default. Another point how to `carry` db connection on separated request ? Use `MongoClient`, like this `from pymongo import MongoClient;c = MongoClient('localhost',27017);c[param_X].what_you_do_with_this`

Comment: mongoengine is provide  Model functionality if i using MongoClient then fetch query is  db.foo.find_one(...) if i using mongoengine just do model.objects() its easy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use different databases. Just use different collections for every use-case you have and wrap the application with [Flask-MongoEngine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/blob/master/README.rst).

PS. Take a better look about how variables-scopes work in  Flask.